# Where can I find a clean API for Visual Basic development?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I am completely new to ASP.NET programming, and was asked to work on a small project involving ASP.NET, VB (which I am new to as well) and Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Being used to php/java I was hoping to find some kind of similar API to php.net and the javadoc. It would be very useful to have as I would prefer to work with a text editor, instead of using DreamWeaver or Visual Web Developer.

In the project I basically only need to use ASP.NET to read from a SQL 2005 database and write to JSON files. Could anyone please give me some pointers on where to find a clean and decent API to work with? I would also appreciate any input and tips I could get to get started working on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only need to use ASP.NET to read from a SQL 2005 database and write to JSON files

You might want to take a look at ASP.NET MVC.

You controllers can return a [`JsonReasult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx) which will automatically result in JSON being sent. No need to define any markup.

Answer (score 4):

> I would prefer to work with a text editor, instead of using DreamWeaver or Visual Web Developer.

Imo this is a mistake in .Net.  The platform was built with the IDE in mind.  You really will be able to get a lot more done, and do it better, if you let yourself learn to use Visual Studio.

That said, the place to look for .Net documentation is, of course, the MSDN Library.  Maybe start on this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2.aspx

Comment: I see, my concern with the IDE is that I would like to avoid auto-generated code to maintain a good overview, as I'm still very much learning. Thank you for the input though, I suppose that I probably should be migrating to the Visual tools.

Comment: Note that I'm not saying you have to use the forms designer for asp.net.  You can still type in your asp.net markup manually just fine.

Answer (score 1):

> "Could anyone please give me some
>   pointers on where to find a clean and
>   decent API to work with?"

If you want to develop a VB.NET application, you have to use the VB.NET programming language; there are no other APIs available.

Where does javadoc fit into this?  That's just markup you apply to your source code to create documentation.  .NET has its own system which works in the same way but is built on XML.

As Joel says, Visual Studio has everything you need.  It features a visual editor but also gives you access to all the source code.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to have the IDE to develop ASP.Net application. It will be much easier using it. You can find docs and articles on developing on ASP.Net in this site. its a nice one.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211027112438/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/default.aspx#Tools2
https://web.archive.org/web/20210513213529/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/042705-1.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20210802161558/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110905-1.aspx

> work on a small project involving ASP.NET, VB (which I am new to as well) and Microsoft SQL Server 2005

It might not be VB, it might be VB.Net?